# Prove: $A\cap (B - C) = (A \cap B) - (A \cap C)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

**Prove:** $A \cap (B - C) = (A \cap B) − (A \cap C)$

I can understand this using Venn Diagrams, however I am struggling to translate this into a formal proof.

Comment: *hint*: start with $x \in A \cap (B-C)$, then $x \in A$ and $x \in B-C$. Consequently $x \in A$ and $x \in B$ but $x \not\in C$. Can you proceed now?

Comment: Would I be correct to then say: suppose X ∈ C and X ∈ A - B, then X ∈ C and X ∈ A but X ∉ B ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most common strategy for proving that sets $S=T$ is to show that $S\subset T$ and $T\subset S$.  And the most common strategy for proving $S\subset T$ is to prove that $(x\in S) \implies (x\in T)$ for any element $x$ in the universe of the problem.  So let's do that!

First, let $x\in A\cap (B-C)$ be given.  This means that $x\in A$ and $x\in B-C$, meaning that $x\in B$ and $x\notin C$.  In other words, $x\in A\cap B$ but $x\notin A\cap C$, so $x\in (A\cap B)-(A\cap C)$.

Conversely, let $x\in(A\cap B)-(A\cap C)$ be given.  Then $x\in A\cap B$ and $x\notin A\cap C$.  Since $x\in A\cap B$, $x\in A$ and $x\in B$.  But $x\notin A\cap C$, so it must be that $x\notin C$.  Since $x\in B$ and $x\notin C$, $x\in B-C$.  Therefore, $x\in A\cap (B-C)$.

Answer (score 2):

To show that two sets are equal you normaly show the two relations $\subseteq$ and $\supseteq$.

This is how it is done, where I write it down explanatory and not how I would do so in a mathematical proof.

So we first want to show that $A\cap (B-C)\subseteq (A\cap B)-(A\cap C)$

So let $x\in A\cap (B-C)$.
By definition of $\cap$ this means that $x\in A$ and $x\in B-C$.
By definition of $-$ we have that $B-C$ implies $x\in B$ and $x\notin C$.

Now we have $x\in A$ and $x\in B$. So $x\in A\cap B$. (By definitino of $\cap$)
Since $x\in A$ and $x\notin C$, it is $x\notin A\cap C$. (By definition of $\cap$)

So $x\in (A\cap B)-(A\cap C)$ (By defintion of $-$)

Now show $A\cap (B-C)\supseteq (A\cap B)-(A\cap C)$.

Start like this: Let $x\in (A\cap B)-(A\cap C)$. Then ...

The proof is done (exactly) like above.

Answer (score 2):

$$A \cap (B-C) = A \cap (B \cap C^\complement)$$ while

$$(A\cap B) - (A \cap C) = (A \cap B) \cap (A \cap C)^\complement = \\
(A \cap B) \cap (A^\complement \cup C^\complement) (\text{ de Morgan) } =\\
(A \cap B \cap A^\complement) \cup (A \cap B \cap C^\complement) = A \cap B \cap C^\complement$$

so we have equality (the first component of the final union is empty).

Answer (score 1):

Here it is an approach based on the definition of difference and the De Morgan Laws:

\begin{align*}
(A\cap B) - (A\cap C) & = (A\cap B)\cap(\overline{A\cap C}) = (A\cap B)\cap(\overline{A}\cup\overline{C})\\
& = (A\cap B\cap\overline{A})\cup(A\cap B\cap\overline{C})\\
& = A\cap B\cap\overline{C} = A\cap(B - C)
\end{align*}

Comment: At the first equality, your A accidentally becomes a B.

Comment: This is just a typo. The reasoning still applies. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: I know, just wanted to be clear for the op!